# set result of method to variable i can return in text field form c#

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns a string from a database based on what i pass to it. The method works but i need to display the result in a textbox on a form. But when i run it the result i keep getting is "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]". I cant work this out. I try looping through the interest variable with for loop but this doesn't work either.

```
var interest = GetValue2(tvp, connectionString); -- this is my method that returns a string
textBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", interest.ToString());
```

this returns "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" to textbox2. Any ideas what im missing here? thanks

PART 2:

```
    public static List<String> GetValue2(DataTable tvp, String connectionString)
    {

        List<String> items = new List<String>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[...]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter tvpParameter = new SqlParameter();
            tvpParameter.ParameterName = "@..";
            tvpParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
            tvpParameter.Value = tvp;
            tvpParameter.TypeName = "[dbo].[....]";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(tvpParameter);

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((String)rdr["id"]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        return items;           
    }
```

Comment: `textBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", interest);`

Answer (score 2):

Could you share the `GetValue2` method? Probably you are calling `ToString()` on `List` in that method and it that case the `GetValue2` method returns

"System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]"

Example:

```
var test = new List<string>{"some text"};
test.ToString(); // returns System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

**Update:**

Because the method `GetValue2` returns `List<string>` avoid calling `.ToString()` on `interest`

```
var interest = GetValue2(tvp, connectionString); // returns List<string>
textBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", interest);
```

There's also the issue of the `List<string> items` inside the `GetValue2()` not being populated.

Here's the corrected method:

```cs
public static List<String> GetValue2(DataTable tvp, String connectionString)
{

    List<String> items = new List<String>();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[...]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter tvpParameter = new SqlParameter();
        tvpParameter.ParameterName = "@..";
        tvpParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
        tvpParameter.Value = tvp;
        tvpParameter.TypeName = "[dbo].[....]";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(tvpParameter);

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                items.Add((String)rdr["id"]);
            }
        }
    }
    return items;           
}
```

Comment: Hey, i added the method. It returns a list of strings and works when im working with just the console but seem to be having the issue when returning the results to the text box

Comment: it returns blank now. the method works because when i debug i see the correct results. I think the issue is with assigning the method results to interest variable. When i try and return the results from the interest variable its blank. Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanGadson The `items` list inside the `GetValue2()` method is not being populated.